# Why won't the data display using Angular?

Tags: angular, api, httprequest, httpresponse

I am having a bit of trouble displaying data. It seems to be retrieving the data when I make a request but I am not sure I am tapping into it correctly as whenever I make a get request nothing is being displayed. Would appreciate any advice.

api.service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, retry, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Story } from './data';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class APIService {

  data: Story[] = [];

  Base_URL ="https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/8863.json?print=pretty";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getStories(): Observable<Story> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.Base_URL).pipe(
      map((response: any) => { return response['data'] as Story }),
      tap((_: Story) => { console.log('Details: {{data}}') })
    ) 
  }

}
```

news-stories.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { APIService } from '../api.service';
import { Story } from '../data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-news-stories',
  templateUrl: './news-stories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news-stories.component.css']
})
export class NewsStoriesComponent implements OnInit {

  data: Story = {by : '', descendants : '', id : '', kids : [ ], score : '', time : '', title : '', type : '', url : ''};
  subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  constructor(private APIService: APIService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  get() {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.APIService.getStories()
        .subscribe((story: Story) => { this.data = story })
    );
  }

}
```

news-stories.component.html:

```
<div>
    <button class="mat-stroked-button" (click) = get()> Get</button>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let item of data | keyvalue">
    <p>{{item.key}} : {{item.value}}</p>
</div>
```

data.ts:

```
export interface Story {
    by : string;
    descendants : string;
    id : string;
    kids : [ ],
    score : string;
    time : string;
    title : string;
    type : string;
    url : string;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Ideally, you could drop the code into a online IDE like https://stackblitz.com 
and immediately someone can get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.

Comment: Your code looks okay at first glance. What happens when you simply put {{ data | json }} in your template?

Comment: When I add {{data | json}} I can see the interface data but when I make the get request it just disappears. In the html file where the data should be all I can see on the inspector is: <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": null
}-->

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, the only issue is that in your `map`, you are expecting to get `response.data` or `response['data']`, the response doesn't have that property, leave it as:

```js
getStories(): Observable<Story> {
    return this.http.get(this.Base_URL).pipe( // you don't need to add .get<any>, your function already is saying the return type <Story>
      map((response: any) => response as Story), // you don't need curly brackets, and the keyword return
      tap((_: Story) => console.log('Details: {{data}}')) //same here
    ) 
 }
```